# How and where to add Named Window using EPL in NEsper?

Tags: c#, window, named, epl, nesper

I already have the `createstatement` function and have successfully detected a simple event.  My problem now is to process a complex event using EPL.

I need to process both simple and complex events in the same process. I thought I could use `namedwindow` to process it, but I don't know how and where to place the `namedwindow` command inside my program since I have not yet mastered the EPL language and NEsper.

Where should I be calling `namedwindow`?

Comment: I've improved the English grammar a bit, and broken it down into simple paragraphs.  What this question really needs is a minimal code sample that demonstrates the problem; if you can add that, you're much more likely to attract high-quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the NEsper test classes that test named windows and looking at the examples. Among the test classes you could look for eamples for join at TestNamedWindowJoin or subquery for instance in TestInfraSubquery.

Test classes:

- https://github.com/espertechinc/nesper/tree/master/NEsper/NEsper.Tests/regression/nwtable
- https://github.com/espertechinc/nesper/blob/master/NEsper/NEsper.Tests/regression/nwtable/TestNamedWindowJoin.cs
- https://github.com/espertechinc/nesper/blob/master/NEsper/NEsper.Tests/regression/nwtable/TestInfraSubquery.cs

Examples:
https://github.com/espertechinc/nesper/tree/master/NEsper/NEsper.Examples/example

Comment: Thank you for sharing all those link.. I really need it, but before this I don't know where to find.. I need to explore this example first. If anything, I hope u don't mind if I ask for help. ^_^... @user650839